# AWS cloudformation custom resource to generate config file for another lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I want to generate a lambda's config file dynamically (Basically application config) during the AWS stack creation.

Once all the configs are ready then only the particular lambda should be created along with that newly generated file. Can I achieve this using custom resources in AWS cloud formation?

I searched but only with lambda or commandrunner or SNS topics only there. No custom resource to write or modify local files. Could someone provide a sample or guidance to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's some options I see for your use case:

- Use a Lambda based CF Custom Resource for your config file logic. Load base files from S3 or checkout from Version Control (git) within the Custom Resource Lambda function.
- Execute a custom script within your build/deploy process. E.g. you have a build.sh script that contains the commands to deploy the CF templates, but first you execute another script that creates the config file and places it in the source folder for the lambda function.
- Use a Docker Image based Lambda function and include your config file logic in the Dockerfile. You can also use AWS SAM to build the docker image within the CF deployment.
- Use AWS CDK and its concept of bundling for lambda functions.

Comment: It partially solves my problem. It's kind of a lengthy process but ok.